# Cant query by string in firestore. RuntimeException Field "latitude" is not a java.lang.String

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I am writing small application using firestore for android in java. I am trying to query by latitude field in collection. There are some users in my collection, which should be returned by this query - even firestore console in browser return those users.

The problem is that I get an error every time:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Field 'latitude' is not a java.lang.String

My code:

```
public Map<String, Object> getUsersBasedOnBounds2(LatLngBounds bounds){
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    Query query = db.collection(collection).whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("latitude", (int)bounds.northeast.latitude);
    query.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
            Log.d(TAG, queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments().toString());
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : queryDocumentSnapshots){
                Log.d(TAG, doc.getString("latitude"));
            }
        }
    });
    return null;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try with `doc.getValue("latitude").toString()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're asking the API to retrieve the `String` field `latitude`, the error informs you that there is no `latitude` field that is a `String. As the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#getString(java.lang.String)) says:

> Throws `RuntimeException` if the value is not a String.

The value of the `latitude` field is likely stored as a number, in which case you can either directly get it as a number. Since the value is most likely stored as a double, that'd be done by calling [`getDouble`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#getDouble(java.lang.String)):

```
doc.getDouble("latitude")
```

Or get it as a generic value by calling [`get`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#get(java.lang.String)), and convert that to a string:

```
String.valueOf(doc.get("latitude"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're printing Log `Log.d(TAG, doc.getString("latitude"));`

Instead  of that use:

```
Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(doc.getString("latitude")));
```